# xend doesn't bring up the vif interfaces

Tags: virtualization, xen

I'm trying working with Xen and I've tryed to build up a virtual machine in domU.
I'm using the following configuration for the domU

```
kernel = '/media/home_separata/domU_kernel/boot/vmlinuz-linux'                  
ramdisk = '/media/home_separata/domU_kernel/boot/initramfs-linux.img'
name = "domU_Arch_linux"
root = '/dev/xvda1 ro'
disk = ['file:/media/home_separata/domU_kernel/arch_linux_kernel.img,xvda1,w']
vif = ['mac=aa:::10:11:f1,ip=192.168.0.2,bridge=xenbr0']
```

when I try to create this vm with "xm create" it works fine except that it doesn't bring up vif interfaces in dom0, so the virtual machine had no access to the net.

Does anyone have any idea about this problem?

Comment: Use the virt-manger to see if the vif interface is enabled ?

Comment: What settings do you use for networking in XEN? Please post the according lines of your `xend-config.sxp` file.

Comment: What does you xend.log say during DomU creation?

Answer (score 0):

Your config file should probably call a Xen networking script to setup apropriate interface on xenbr0. Set up last line like this -

```
vif = ['mac=aa:::10:11:f1,ip=192.168.0.2,bridge=xenbr0,script=vif-bridge']
```

Comment: The default should be configured in **xend-config.sxp**.