# xl create doesn't bring up console

Tags: virtualization, xen

I've tryed to run VM in Xen 4.2 using xl command (for what I get this should be standard toolstack, while xm is deprecated).

In this case I've the following configuration file

```
kernel = '/media/home_separata/domU_kernel/boot/vmlinuz-linux'                  
ramdisk = '/media/home_separata/domU_kernel/boot/initramfs-linux.img'
name = "domU_Arch_linux"
memory = "512"
root = '/dev/xvda1 ro'
disk = ['file:/media/home_separata/domU_kernel/arch_linux_kernel.img,xvda1,w']
vif = ['mac=aa:::10:11:f1,ip=192.168.0.2,bridge=xenbr0']
```

when I try to start the virtual machine with xl create it seems it works (it also bring up the vif interfaces) but if I try to connect via xl console it gives an error:

```
xenconsole: Could not read tty from store: No such file or directory
```

the fun fact is that the I've the [problem inverse](https://serverfault.com/q/371155/114451) using xend/xm (in that case xend doesn't bring up vif interfaces but activate console).

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It's seems I've solved the problem: apparently for some reason at startup the system didn't bring up the module xen-gntdev, manually loading this module made it work the console.

```
modprobe xen-gntdev 2
```

See the [References](http://xen-changelog.narkive.com/iaLYgkq6/xen-4-1-testing-tools-init-d-linux-xencommons-load-evtchn-and-gntdev-modules)

Answer (score 0):

Check if xenconsoled is running. If not, start it.

If this doesn't help you, look at the /etc/inittab file of your VM and see if this line is there:

```
co:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty console
```

If not, add it :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: No, it didn't work, anyway thanks for the try. Have you got any idea on what the problem could be? But more important how is possibile that with xend console its started?

Comment: Well, the xl toolstack is still new and contains some issues. Besides of that, I have no further ideas. Sorry!